# MySQL Workbench Query returns 1 row, but same query in Jdbc returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I wrote a query that returns 1 row when I run it in MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT lot_num, block_num, base_price, SUM(price) AS options_price FROM lots AS l 
INNER JOIN models AS m ON l.model_id = m.id 
INNER JOIN lot_options AS lo ON l.id = lo.lot_id 
INNER JOIN options AS o ON lo.option_id = o.id 
GROUP BY l.id
```

When I try to run that in Jdbc I am getting 0 results. Here is how I have formatted the string for Jdbc:

SELECT lot_num, block_num, base_price, SUM(price) AS options_price FROM lots AS l INNER JOIN models AS m ON l.model_id = m.id INNER JOIN lot_options AS lo ON l.id = lo.lot_id INNER JOIN options AS o ON lo.option_id = o.id GROUP BY l.id;

This does not provide me with an error or anything. Just an empty result set.

I cannot figure out where I am going wrong with this query! Please bestow your SQL mastery upon me!

Comment: Can you remove one by one conditions and see any results and find the problem. without DB data I cannot tell anything here.

Comment: If your query is identical, is the connect user identical?

Comment: `select * from lots` <= what's the return in ResultSet?

Comment: Have you tried executing the formatted query in SQL WorkBench again?

Comment: This is just a testing database, so there are only 3 results in the lots table. When I run `select * from lots;` it returns all 3 entries.

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the right database, and that the data your querying is actually committed?

Comment: Definitely the correct database. The query I posted below worked for me. I am too new to SQL to understand the finer differences at play here. The query above this comment works in Workbench. The query below works in both workbench and in Jdbc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't know enough about JOIN statements. The many-to-many tables need LEFT OUTER joins. I have no idea why my original query worked in Workbench, but not in my Jdbc connection. This works in both!

```
SELECT lot_num, block_num, models.base_price, SUM(o.price) FROM lots 
INNER JOIN models ON models.id = lots.model_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN lot_options AS lo ON lots.id = lo.lot_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN options AS o ON lo.option_id = o.id
GROUP BY lots.id
```